# Exporting same format to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

The command below I took straight from Microsoft's website.  It works and produces results like this:

> Name, PasswordLastSet, and LastLogonStamp.

Now, I need to know what I have to put in to export it to CSV with the same format i.e. name, passwordlastset, lastlogonstamp etc.

I know nothing about PS scripting, so this may seem like a dumb question but I can't figure it out.

```
$d = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-180)

Get-ADUser -Filter '(PasswordLastSet -lt $d) -or (LastLogonTimestamp -lt $d)' -Properties PasswordLastSet,LastLogonTimestamp | ft Name,PasswordLastSet,@{N="LastLogonTimestamp";E={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp)}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final text that worked is here:

$d = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-180)

Get-ADUser -Filter '(PasswordLastSet -lt $d) -or (LastLogonTimestamp -lt $d)' -Properties PasswordLastSet,LastLogonTimestamp | Select-Object Name,PasswordLastSet,@{N="LastLogonTimestamp";E={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp)}} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Another.csv -NoTypeInformation

Thank you all for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Format-Table `ft` only works in the console view - Use `Select-Object` for anything else, and `Export-CSV` for outputting to a file. Variables like `$d` won't get expanded inside single quotes. Try something like this:

```
$d = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-180).ToFileTime()

Get-ADUser -Filter "(LastLogon -lt $d) -or (PasswordLastSet -lt $d)" -Properties LastLogon,PasswordLastSet |
  Select-Object Name,PasswordLastSet,@{N="LastLogonTimestamp";E={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}} | 
  Export-CSV -Path 'C:\Folder\File.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Edit: you must convert your initial date to `FileTime` before filtering, and you must filter on these specific property names

Comment: Thanks for your response @rohit, when I put that in I get a set of errors... 

GetADUser: Error parsing query '(PasswordLastSet -lt ) -or (LastLogonTimestamp -lt )' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '22'.

Comment: @KVal I've fixed my answer - mixed up which AD properties use `DateTime` instead of `FileTime` format

Comment: based on your reply, I was able to make it work by using this:

Get-ADUser -Filter '(PasswordLastSet -lt $d) -or (LastLogonTimestamp -lt $d)' -Properties PasswordLastSet,LastLogonTimestamp | ft Name,PasswordLastSet,@{N="LastLogonTimestamp";E={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp)}} | Export-CSV -Path C:\file.csv -NoTypeInformation

It created a .csv file, but the data inside the file is gibberish.  I would screenshot it but I don't think I can on this site.  It came out with 6 columns with data on row 1 and column A has this "27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c" for 180 rows

Comment: @KVal you *must* use `Select-Object` instead of `ft`. `ft` (or `Format-Table`) adds a bunch of formatting data that can't really be piped to commands like `Export-CSV`.

Comment: Thanks Cpt.Whale, that did it.